# How to implement this string match in a dictionary?

Tags: java, algorithm

For example, I have a sentence:

```
This is a trash bag.
```

, which is stored in a List, in which each element is a word:

```
List<String> wrodList = new ArrayList<String>;
```

I have another dictionary which stores the word-freq pair:

```
Map<String, Integer> allWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

A few examples:

```
  bag 300
  trash 250
  trash bag 100
  big trash bag 50
```

Now I want to go through the wordList

```
["this", "is", "a", "trash", "bag"]
```

and want to check whether there is a phrase from the sentence that matches an entry in the dictionary. In this case, ["trash", "bag"] should match the entry "trash bag" in the dictionary.

I am thinking of this algorithm:

1. Reconstruct all possible phrases from the token list:

   ["this", "is", "a", "trash", "bag"]=>

   ```
   this is a trash bag
   this is a trash
   this is a
   this is

   is a trash bag
   is a trash
   is a 

   a trash bag
   a trash

   trash bag
   ```

Then do a lookup in the dictionary for each of these phrases. As soon as a match with a dictionary key is found, returns; 
This naive algorithm seems working (not tested), but won't be efficient, since it has to construct lots of useless phrases for potential matches which must fail.

If I extract all map keys, break them by space and insert them into another List, I will get from the dictionary keys:

```
[[trash], [bag], [trash, bag], [big, trash, bag]]
```

then try to matches all these phrases from the sentence with this list. This should work better?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you limited to the current data structure? Because I would probably look at implementing a tree structure.

Comment: What's your suggestion? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

**If the order of words are important:**

You can condiser maintaining the dictionary of word-freq pair in suffix tree.
Search can be done with O(n) with KMP Algorithm of searching for patterns in string. you can find detailed discussion on suffix tree [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pattern-searching-set-8-suffix-tree-introduction/) and KMP algorithm [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=11902).

**In case order of words is not important:**

You can modify the dictionary to hold list of words(in every phrase) in sorted order instead of just the phrase.

For example:

```
[bag] 300
[trash] 250
[bag, trash] 100
[bag, big, trash] 50
```

Then during search.
You may want to split it into words and sort them and generate all combinations of them. (this may be small I guess). Let n is the no.of words in given string, then we have (2 pow n) combinations. A linear search on this will result O(2 pow n). This is definitely a bad solution for bigger n values even for n > 10

Hope it helps!

Comment: "You may want to split it into words and sort them and generate all combinations of them." Does 'it' (given string) refer to entry in dictionary or the sentence?

Comment: What's the purpose of sorting 'big trash bag' to 'bag big trash'? Can you please make your explanation a little more specific? Thanks.

Comment: The sorting will help you avoid checking for all the permutations of the given set of words.